# "BETA" is Latin for still doesn't work?

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes

**"BETA" is Latin for still doesn't work**

what does the above line actually mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a joke, which is spoiled by being wrong on many levels.

"Beta" software is generally functional software in the last stages of testing. It is likely to still have bugs, and is not ready for general release or sale. Beta software can be said to be "still not working".

Beta is the second letter of the *Greek* alphabet. Alpha is the first letter. Alpha software has incomplete functionality. Alpha testing is the first stage of testing. Beta testing is the second.

Some people in QA go to lots of details about what "Alpha" and "Beta" means. The joke is that the description is very short. "Alpha is Greek for 'doesn't work', Beta is Greek for 'still doens't work'!"